# How is the air traffic before thanksgiving?

Tags: usa, airports, dubai, thanksgiving

I am currently in USA and would like to visit my country before thanksgiving (16 November).

I'll be traveling from Newark via Dubai. The connecting flight is from dubai and the time between two flights is only 2 hours and 10 mins.

I want to know whether the connection time is too low?

What are the policies If I miss the connecting flight due to plane being late like only 30 mins before the connecting flight (Emirates)?

Comment: Are you booked through on a single ticket, or are your flights booked on separate tickets? The difference could be significant.

Comment: Single ticket through emirates website.

Comment: That's plenty of time. Your baggage will get checked through and you'll stay airside: so you just have to get off the plane, find your gate and hop on the next plane. Thanksgiving is typically light for international traffic. Domestic in the US is very busy most people stay in country. You may want to get to Newark early, it will be very full the day before Thanksgiving.

Comment: Note:  this is a full week before Thanksgiving (Nov 22nd this year).  Americans don't have that much vacation time, traffic won't be heavy at all

Answer (score 3):

As you're booked through on a single ticket the airline will handle your checked-in baggage for you. You need only get yourself and your hand luggage to the onward flight. From my own experience at Dubai this is easily doable in two hours, and the airline clearly think so since they sold you the ticket.

However, should you miss your connection because your inbound flight is late, Emirates are obliged to book you on the next available flight, so apart from a delay you should have no problems. I can think of worse places than Dubai airport to be held up.

Thanksgiving might have an impact on flights around the US (they'll probably be busier than usual), but won't be a factor elsewhere. Perhaps allow some extra time for check-in at Newark.

Were you booked on separate tickets you'd have to reclaim your baggage and check it in again at Dubai. Two hours would be quite tight, and if you're late you risk losing your onward connection altogether.

Comment: The usual caveats apply: if the incoming flight is late, you might make it but not your luggage. Be prepared for that. If your flight is very late and you miss the connection, you will have to wait for a later flight, which may be the next day depending on your destination. Be prepared for that as well. US airports are very, very busy around Thanksgiving. Arrive early, there might be a lot of traffic on the way, and queues may be very long. If you miss the first flight you are on your own, the whole round trip ticket may be cancelled.